# Angular filter having no effect when using ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I seem to be missing something here with filtering an ng-repeat with a search box.

```
<li ng-if="searchTab"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"  ng-model="search" >
  </li>
```

and the ng-repeat

```
<div dir-paginate="saving in savings| orderBy:orderByField:!reverseSort| filter:search | filter:{retailer:filterBy}|itemsPerPage:10" class="list-group-item">
```

is there any obvious reason why the filter doesnt do anything when i type in the search box?

Edit - I notice that if i remove the ng-if it works. Is there any way of using both?

Comment: Can you provide a JS fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ng-if use ng-show.

```
<li ng-show="searchTab"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"  ng-model="search" >
  </li>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed without.

Answer (score 1):

If the value for searchTab is false during the initialisation phase of the controller then the input div is not evaluated. Hence the ng-model directive wont create the variable 'search' on the controller scope. So please declare 'search' as a variable in your controller.

Comment: It was actually declared but this morning i had the idea of changing the ng-if to ng-show and it worked straight away.